# Uploading images from app to server using PHP

Tags: php, android, angularjs, image, onsen-ui

I have a cross platform app built using Monaca/Onsen UI and AngularJS.
The app allows users to take images (photos) and this is working as intended.

Next, I want to upload the images to my server for storage and future use.

I have the app image capture working as intended and I have implemented a PHP solution on the server that *appears* to be working, but I cant seem to see the images.

My app code for capture and upload looks as follows (at the moment I just access the image library and select images for testing - rather than capturing them - but both solutions working):

```
$scope.takePicture = function getImage() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function (message) {
        alert('get picture failed');
    }, {
        quality: 100, destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    });
}

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    var params = new Object();
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";
    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, "http://mysite/public/api/savephotos.php", function (result) {
        alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(result)); // Success: {"bytesSent":42468,"responseCode":200,"response":"","objectId":""}
    }, function (error) {
        alert("Fail: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    }, options);
}
```

From the *success* response it seems that images are being sent, but when I check the folder where the images are supposed to be saved to (*C:\xampp\htdocs\public\api\upload*), the folder is empty. The server side details are Sximo template using Laravel framework hosted on AWS.

The PHP code that handles the server side saving looks as below:

```
<?php
    // Connect to Database
    $DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    $DB_USER = 'root';
    $DB_PASS = '';
    $DB_NAME = 'myDB';

    $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    // Allow Headers
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    $new_image_name = urldecode($_FILES["file"]["name"]).".jpg";
    // Move files into upload folder
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'C:\xampp\htdocs\public\api\upload'.$new_image_name);

mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

However, the *C:\xampp\htdocs\public\api\upload* is empty - with no images sent to it. I do have a file called *uploadimage* that has been sent to the directory *C:\xampp\htdocs\public\api* that appears to be updated with each test - but this is a empty (0kb) file.

Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the asynktask that I use to send image from the gallery app to server

```
public static class requestPostReportPhoto extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Bitmap image;
    String JSON_STRING;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        String fileUrl = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM+"/"+"albumName"+"/"+"photoName";
        image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUrl);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String fileUrl = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM+"/"+"albumName"+"/"+"photoName";

        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        String response = "Error";



        String urlString = "yourUrlServer";

        try {
            File file = new File(fileUrl);
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.addRequestProperty("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);


            dos = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\"" + "PHOTONAME" + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);



            Log.d("MediaPlayer", "Headers are written");

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];


            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }


            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            StringBuilder responseSB = new StringBuilder();
            int result = connection.getResponseCode();
            BufferedReader br;
            // 401 - 422 - 403 - 404 - 500
            if (result == 401 || result == 422 || result == 403 || result == 404 || result == 500)
            {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
            }
            else {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            }
            while ( (JSON_STRING = br.readLine()) != null)
                responseSB.append(JSON_STRING+ "\n");

            Log.d("MediaPlayer","File is written");
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            br.close();


            response = responseSB.toString().trim();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.d("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }

        return response;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("SERVER RESPONSE ->",result)
    }





    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

}
```